# Test specification in testlink to be modified with 'Notes' custom field adding to filter criteria

Tags: php, mysql, testing, testlink

[image: You can see 'Notes' text area.I added it. Now I need this as a filter criteria.]Need to add filter criteria called 'Notes' . In attached screenshot I added the text area for Notes section. Now I need to search with applying this search criteria. Which Testlink files to be modified?

Comment: this question is incomplete

Comment: Added screenshot. Let me know if any more information is required.